# Загрузка AssetBundles в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Для загрузки дополнений в игре использую assetbundles, которые лежат на хостинге. У меня на всех моих устройствах все работает отлично, но вот некоторые пользователи не могут загрузить совсем ничего. Причем я попросил одного из них скачать файлик дополнения по прямой ссылке в браузере и у него все скачалось, но в приложении постоянно выскакивает ошибка. Может кто знает с чем это может быть связано?

```
private IEnumerator LoadBundleFromServer(int addonId, Action<AssetBundle, int, Hash128> response, Action<float> progress)
{

    while (!Caching.ready)
    {
        yield return null;
    }

    //Check available space

    int spaceAvailable = DiskUtils.CheckAvailableSpace();
    if (spaceAvailable < MaxSpaceForDownloading) {
        LoadingError(2);
        Debug.LogErrorFormat("Not enough space");
        yield break;
    }

    //Check version

    var request = UnityWebRequest.Get(GetUrlOfBundle(addonId, 1));
    yield return request.SendWebRequest();
    Hash128 version = new Hash128();

    if (!request.isHttpError && !request.isNetworkError)
    {
        version = Hash128.Parse(request.downloadHandler.text.ToString().Trim());
    }
    request.Dispose();

    if (!version.isValid) {
        LoadingError(1);
        Debug.LogErrorFormat("error request version");
        yield break;
    }
    Debug.Log("Version to download - " + version);


    //Start downloading
    UnloadCurrentAssetBundle();
    if (!Caching.ClearAllCachedVersions(GetUrlOfBundle(addonId, 2))) {

        LoadingError(1);
        yield break;
    }

    string url = GetUrlOfBundle(addonId, 0);

    request = UnityWebRequestAssetBundle.GetAssetBundle(url, version);

    request.SendWebRequest();
    while (!request.isDone)
    {
        progress(request.downloadProgress);

        yield return null;
    }
    progress(1f);
    if (!request.isHttpError && !request.isNetworkError)
    {
        UnloadCurrentAssetBundle();
        response(DownloadHandlerAssetBundle.GetContent(request), addonId, version);
    }
    else
    {
        LoadingError(1);
        Debug.LogErrorFormat("error request [{0}, {1}]", url, request.error);
        yield break;
    }

    request.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Для таких вопросов все-таки надо указать ошибку, которая возникает, лучше вместе с логом юнити, иначе будет сложно вам помочь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело было в том, что у меня ссылка была http и на версиях андроид 9 и выше выскакивала ошибка при загрузке. С https все работает отлично

Comment: Чтобы дополнить свой вопрос, просим вас воспользоваться опцией редактирования. Кнопку «Опубликовать ответ» следует использовать только для исчерпывающих ответов на вопросы. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/398622)

Comment: @RuslanSemenov Это как раз ответ, почитайте ещё раз и вопрос  и ответ.

Comment: раз уж вы сами ответили на свой вопрос, пометьте ответ правильным и закройте вопрос